# Am I single or three?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

> I have four legs. But I am not a Table.
>
> I have two legs. But I am not a Kangaroo.
>
> I have three legs. But I am not a Stool.

Can you guess us?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sphinx-related riddle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25604/sphinx-related-riddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you a

> man?

Four legs:

> A man walking with crutches

Two legs:

> A man

Three legs:

> A man walking with a cane.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> vehicle

Because

> cars have four tyres,bikes has two tyres,and auto or rickshaw(in india) has three tyres.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> human?

because

> a baby uses all four a man uses 2 legs and 
>  a old    man uses his two legs and a cane

Comment: It looks like this answer restates content that is already thoroughly expressed in another answer. In the future, please be sure to read through other answers on the site before adding your own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could make this fit with a lot of things.

> You are three separate things, which I think is valid according to your question. You are a Chair (four legs), then a Person (two legs), then a Tripod (three legs).

The existing answers also fit.

Comment: To be technical, a chair has 4 legs, and 3 legs, as well as 2 legs.

Comment: Well I guess that makes some of the other answers incorrect too. Back to searching :)