# What has 4 limbs in the morning, 2 in afternoon, and 3 in the sunset

Tags: riddle

What has 4 limbs in the morning, 2 in afternoon, and 3 in the sunset...

but has 6 in the daytime and 6 in the night.

(And also has 2 in predawn and 2 in noontime)

Comment: Should go quick. Couldn't figure out if it's a duplicate. I googled the answer and just got a bunch of articles about sphinxes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25604/sphinx-related-riddle

Comment: Could be, if you can explain how he has 6 limbs : ).  Okay I may have been joking about the sphinxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Letters.
>
> If "limbs" refers to parts that stick out, specifically parts of letters that are above or below the normal height of a lowercase letter (like *x*), then letters have 4 limbs in ***th**e morn**i**n**g***, 2 in *a**ft**ernoon*, 3 in ***th**e sunse**t***, 6 in ***th**e **d**a**yti**me*, 6 in ***th**e n**ight***, 2 in ***p**re**d**awn*, and 2 in *noon**ti**me*.